# how Two Double values equality always coming false even if the values are equal in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

Hi Here I'm comparing to double values equal or not. but its returing always false even if both Double values are Equal.

```
let latestlogoValue = log(Double(125))/log(5.0)
let latestlogIntValue:Int = Int(latestlogoValue)
print(latestlogoValue)
print(Double(latestlogIntValue))
print(Double(latestlogIntValue) == Double(latestlogoValue)) //Always returning false
```

Answer (score 3):

Double or float value comparison with == sign, will not give you the exact answer. You may think that the two values are equal to each other but they are slightly different. Doubles are stored differently in memory. You can test it by printing as String like below-

```
print(String(format: "%.20f", Double(latestlogoValue))) //3.00000000000000044409

print(String(format: "%.20f", Double(latestlogIntValue))) //3.00000000000000000000
```

So you can update your comparison function as

```
func isDoubleEqual(_ first: Double, _ second: Double) -> Bool {
    return fabs(first - second) < Double.ulpOfOne
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happened because of Double type's precision
If we print your values

```
print(String(format: "a float number: %.55f", latestlogoValue))
print(String(format: "a float number: %.55f", Double(latestlogIntValue)))
```

we'll see difference in values:

```
a float number: 3.00000000000000044408920985006261616945266723632812500
a float number: 3.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So the values are different, if you need to compare float or double values use comparing them with some precision

Answer (score 0):

Look at the precesion values are different they are not identical.

Just print them out.

```
print(Double(latestlogoValue).debugDescription) // 3.0000000000000004
print(Double(latestlogIntValue).debugDescription)  // 3.0
```

And you are comparing the same which results always false.

```
print(Double(latestlogIntValue) == Double(latestlogoValue))
// 3.0000000000000004 == 3.0 results false obvious
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        let latestlogoValue = log(Double(125))/log(5.0)
        let latestlogIntValue:Int = Int(latestlogoValue)
        print(latestlogoValue)
        print(Double(latestlogIntValue))
        print(Double(latestlogIntValue) == Double(latestlogoValue))
```

Here Double(latestlogIntValue) & Double(latestlogoValue)) are getting different values . Compare the values with Int you will get true

```
print(Int(latestlogIntValue) == Int(latestlogoValue)) // true
```